# 1D-Array matching breaks when data exists in rows above matching data on spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a command button on a userform that will match strings from two textboxes with data in specific columns on a "Database" sheet, if a match is found it copies the row to another sheet.

The code works and matches data from the sheet when the matched data is the "first" in the database. Meaning, the match data can be in row 1, 2, 3, 10 but as long as NO data exist before it the match works.

Problem: Match breaks when data exists in rows above the matched criteria. I get a match return of False when it should True. When I move the data to be the "first" data it works.

Screenshots to help illustrate:

***Match Criteria***
[image]

***--Works--***
[image]

***Returns True on Locals***
[image]

***--Breaks--***

***Match Fails***
[image]
***Returns False in Locals***
[image]

I am using an array that lines up the indexes with the columns I am searching so I don't have to sort the data. But I did try and sort it and the same issue occurred. I also made sure all the cells in the range I am searching are of format "General", just in in case. I am not "seeing" what else it could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub run_check_but_Click()
    Const COL_STATUS As Long = 4
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsSyn As Worksheet
    Dim tRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim tempList(1 To 9) As String
    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim rCol As Range, c As Range

    Set wsData = Sheets("Database")
    Set rCol = wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(3, 4), wsData.Cells(100, 4))

    'Set TargetSheet and clear the previous contents
    Set wsSyn = Sheets("Syn_Calc")
    wsSyn.Range("A3:G" & wsSyn.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1).ClearContents
    tRow = 3

    'Set an array of strings, based on the index matching the column to search for each
    tempList(5) = curbase_box.Text      'Column "E" (5)
    tempList(6) = dirquote_box.Text     'Column "F" (6)

    For Each c In rCol.Cells
        With c.EntireRow
            If .Cells(COL_STATUS).Value = "Open" Then

                match = False

                For i = LBound(tempList) To UBound(tempList)
                    If tempList(i) <> "" Then
                        match = (.Cells(i).Text = tempList(i))
                        If Not match Then Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

                If match Then
                    'copy values from E-K
                    wsSyn.Cells(tRow, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = _
                         .Cells(5).Resize(1, 7).Value
                    tRow = tRow + 1
                End If

            End If 'open
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Expected Results: When I click on the command button it will search through the columns to match the strings in the textboxes no matter where the data is within the columns and copy the match row to another sheet.

Note: The code will only search for a match if the 4th column("D") has the status of "Open" as you saw in the code. I confirmed this works fine.

Comment: Check the line `If Not match Then Exit For`. I'm not sure what your code is doing exactly but it seems that this line exits the For loop once the previous comparison fails. Perhaps you should rewrite your code to make all the comparisons needed then the loop is skipped if a match is found.

Comment: Thanks Jalal, I will try that

Comment: works fine for me. I just hardcoded your parameters.
[see here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cppo9rZ-1h8jxrUrCLwmRfSnqGEJ1RJy)

Comment: Adirmola! That's great. What formatting do you have for your cells on the Database sheet? That's the only difference I can think of that would cause this behavior. I can also try on separate spreadhseet like you did to see if the issue is replicated.

Comment: General formatting. I can't see how it's related to formatting.

Comment: At first the program wouldn't find a match for some data because some of the cells had "accounting" format. Once I changed the format to general it could read the data to match it.

Comment: @Adirmola! I got it working. It was a simply issue where the Syn_Calc destination cells were not formatted as "General" Once I confirmed that the code worked....lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some debugging lines and another loop. Have a look! Check also the output in the immediate window (Ctrl G)!

**Sample output in the immediate window:**

```
rCol.Address: $D$2:$D$9

start in $D$6
search for CHF
--- search in $E$6
--- search in $F$6
--- search in $G$6
--- search in $H$6
search for 12342
--- search in $E$6
--- search in $F$6
--- search in $G$6
--- search in $H$6

start in $D$7
search for CHF
--- search in $E$7
--- search in $F$7
--- search in $G$7
--- search in $H$7
==============> Match in $H$7

...
...
...
```

**Database**
[image]

**Syn_Calc**
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim c As Range
Dim COL_STATUS As Integer
Dim Match As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim TempList(10) As String
Dim tRow
Dim wsSyn As Worksheet
Dim wsDAta As Worksheet
Dim rCol As Range
Dim MatchRef As String

COL_STATUS = 4

Set wsDAta = Sheets("Database")
Set rCol = wsDAta.Range(wsDAta.Cells(2, 4), wsDAta.Cells(9, 4))
Debug.Print "rCol.Address: "; rCol.Address

'Set TargetSheet and clear the previous contents
Set wsSyn = Sheets("Syn_Calc")
wsSyn.Range("A3:G" & wsSyn.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).ClearContents
tRow = 3

'Set an array of strings, based on the index matching the column to search for each
TempList(5) = "CHF" 'curbase_box.Text      'Column "E" (5)
TempList(6) = "12342" 'dirquote_box.Text     'Column "F" (6)

    For Each c In rCol.Cells

    'Set c = Range("A2")
    With c.EntireRow
            If .Cells(COL_STATUS).Value = "Open" Then

                Match = False
                MatchRef = ""
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print "start in "; c.Address

                For i = LBound(TempList) To UBound(TempList)
                    If TempList(i) <> "" Then
                        Debug.Print "search for "; TempList(i)
                        For j = 5 To 8 'Col E to H
                            Debug.Print "--- search in "; .Cells(1, j).Address
                            Match = (.Cells(1, j).Text = TempList(i))
                            If Match Then
                                'debug: matchRef info
                                MatchRef = "match in " & .Cells(1, j).Address & " - Value : " & TempList(i)
                                Debug.Print "==============> Match in "; .Cells(1, j).Address
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next j
                    If Match Then Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

                If Match Then
                    'copy values from E-K
                    wsSyn.Cells(tRow, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value = _
                         .Cells(5).Resize(1, 7).Value
                    'debug: matchRef info
                    wsSyn.Cells(tRow, 9).Value = MatchRef
                    tRow = tRow + 1
                End If

            End If 'open
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me try this out and let you know. Thanks for this

Comment: Great code except it is pulling a match for Column F - the direction. I get matched copies for all "Longs" or all "Shorts" not for All "CHF" AND "Shorts"

Comment: I did not understood exactly what you are trying to reach! But based on my example you should be able to find a solution for your problem or find the mistakes in your code!

Comment: simple-solution I figured out the issue and it was literally a "simple-solution"...ha! The " destination sheet "Syn_Calc" was not formatted as "General" plus I had a "filter" on the destination data and that was throwing everything off. Once that was changed both your code and mine worked!